# Vue Jest - Create Mock Api server

Tags: unit-testing, vue.js, mocking, jestjs, axios

I want to create a Mock API Server for my Jest tests so that I can define all my backend endpoints and create responses and authentication checks.

I have managed to set up the server and routes by following some of the source code from Chris Fritz "Vue-Enterprice-boilerplate":
https://github.com/chrisvfritz/vue-enterprise-boilerplate/tree/master/tests/unit

```
// jest.config.js

const _ = require("lodash");

process.env.MOCK_API_PORT = process.env.MOCK_API_PORT || _.random(9000, 9999);

module.exports = {
  preset: "@vue/cli-plugin-unit-jest",
  setupFiles: ["./tests/unit/setup"],
  globalSetup: "<rootDir>/tests/unit/global-setup",
  globalTeardown: "<rootDir>/tests/unit/global-teardown",
  testMatch: ["**/(*.)spec.js"],
  moduleFileExtensions: ["js", "jsx", "json", "vue"],
  transform: {
    "^.+\\.vue$": "vue-jest",
    "^.+\\.js$": "babel-jest",
    ".+\\.(css|scss|jpe?g|png|gif|webp|svg|mp4|webm|ogg|mp3|wav|flac|aac|woff2?|eot|ttf|otf)$":
      "jest-transform-stub"
  },
  transformIgnorePatterns: ["/node_modules/(?!vue-spinner)"],  
  testURL: process.env.API_BASE_URL || `http://localhost:${process.env.MOCK_API_PORT}`
};
```

The server runs when the tests starts and I can console log the route files.
I just don't know how the axios call from my Vuex would go with the mock API instead of the real one.
Might need to import axios somewhere in the test to prevent the development URL to be used?

```
/tests/mock-api/routes/auth.js

const Users = require("../resources/users");

module.exports = app => {
  console.log('I can see this during tests!');

  app.post("/api/v1/login", async (req, res) => {
    console.log("I don't see this..");

    await Users.authenticate(req.body)
      .then(user => {
        res.json(user);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        res.status(401).json({ message: error.message });
      });
  });
});
```

```
// /views/Login.spec.js 

import Vue from "vue";
import Vuelidate from "vuelidate";

import Login from "@/views/Login";
import BaseButton from "@/components/Globals/_base-button.vue";
import BaseInput from "@/components/Globals/_base-input.vue";
import BaseLabel from "@/components/Globals/_base-label.vue";

import flushPromises from "flush-promises";

import store from "@/store";
import { shallowMount } from "@vue/test-utils";

Vue.use(Vuelidate);

describe("@/views/Login", () => {
  // other tests..

  it("redirects to posts on successful login", async () => {
    const wrapper = shallowMount(Login, { store, stubs: { BaseInput, BaseButton, BaseLabel } });
    wrapper.vm.$v.$touch();

    const spyDispatch = jest.spyOn(wrapper.vm.$store, "dispatch");

    const username = wrapper.find("#username");
    const password = wrapper.find("#password");

    username.element.value = "johndoe@email.com";
    password.element.value = "passwordz";

    username.trigger("input");
    password.trigger("input");

    await wrapper.find("#submitBtn").trigger("click.prevent");

    await wrapper.vm.$nextTick();

    await flushPromises();

    await expect(spyDispatch).toHaveBeenCalledWith("auth/login", {
      username: username.element.value,
      password: password.element.value
    });

    // @TODO add expect for redirect as well
  });
```

```
// /store/auth.js (vuex)

export const actions = {
  async login({ commit }, { username, password }) {

    console.log("I see this");

    const response = await axios.post("/login", 
    { username, password }, { withCredentials: true });

    console.log("I don't see this");

    // @TODO error handling
    if (!response) return;

    commit("setUser", { ...response.data.user });

    router.push({ name: "Posts" });
  },
```

The login action gets called but I don't get passed the axios.post.

Do I need to import axios somewhere to make sure I get a fresh instance? (Vuex uses one I set the baseURL and headers)

All the other tests and logic works except this.

Comment: I recommend [`axios-mock-adapter`](https://github.com/ctimmerm/axios-mock-adapter) instead.

Comment: Was looking forward to make my approach work, but axios-mock-adapter seems to solve my problems so I will go with that instead. Thanks!